# popover in jquery needs to be converted to javascript for create react app

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, popover, create-react-app

so i found a code for a popover that id like to use but i want to put it in my create-react-app website and one of the important pieces of this code is in JQuery which does not work well with react and i am not familiar with it enough to do so myself. my code needs to be converted into javascript and must work with create react app.

i got the code for the popover [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-awesome-popover. Your code would need to look something like this to workin your react project:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Popover>
    <button>The Target</button>
    <div>The content</div>
  </Popover>,
  document.body
);
```